# How to set UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle textAlignment to center in iPhone iOS4?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

Since upgraded XCode to Version 3.2.3 with iPhone SDK 4 my code doesn't work anymore.

I have a default cell with style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` and want to set the `textAlignment` of `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` to `center`, but nothing happens.
Same code used before now not working anymore. On `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` center alignment still works.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I don't want to use a custom cell only in fact of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why text isn't centered is because the label is only as wide as the text. You can confirm this by setting the background color of the text label:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
```

Setting the cell width manually also doesn't seem to have an effect. So you should really add your own subviews or create your own subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

The docs for `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` even say:

> A style for a cell with a **left-aligned**
>   label across the top and a
>   **left-aligned** label below it in smaller
>   gray text. The iPod application uses
>   cells in this style.

Comment: you're right, but why this worked well in previous iOS 3.0? the documentation wasn't changed since then. I think the textAlignment property is normally not aligning the text rather the label.

Comment: I just tried to run the code that colors the background in different versions of the simulator: it only works in 3.0. From 3.1 on the label is only as wide as the text. I assume they changed it in 3.1 to make drawing faster (because of the smaller views). The documentation says that the labels are left-aligned so this is ok. You can't rely on undocumented features.

Answer (score 1):

here is a two-part solution to alter the label width after rendering, thus allowing the centering to happen:

```
-- (void) updateCenteringForTextLabelInCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell {

    UILabel* label = cell.textLabel;

    label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);

}


-- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

// do your usual

// call the helper method 

[self performSelector:@selector(updateCenteringForTextLabelInCell:) withObject:cell afterDelay:0.05];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok finally the Apple development team answered my bug report from 23rd June 2010:

> "Please try setting the text alignment
>   in layoutSubviews after calling
>   super."