# A workaround to get textAlignment to center in UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100447/how-to-set-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-textalignment-to-center-in-iphone-ios4) (and many many google search results), when we're in a table view, and we set the cells to have `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, we have been forced to align our texts inside the cell label to be on the left.

However I want one of the rows (in fact the row) of my table view to be aligned center... Obviously this wouldn't work:

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

So I've been thinking what I should do instead... I'm not sure how to do it cleanly. The best way I can think of is to change this particular cell so that the style of the cell is  `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, but I don't think the cell property is changeable. Another way that I can think of is to subclass the `UITableViewCell` class, but that seems to be a bit of an overkill just for one table view cell. What do you think I should do to make that one last row aligned center?

EDIT: for those of you who're interested in the answer:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellIdentifierDefault = @"CellDefault";

UITableViewCell *cell; // = [pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  

  if (indexPath.row >= [data count])
        cell = [pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierDefault];
    else
        cell = [pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil && indexPath.row < [data count]) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else if(cell == nil && indexPath.row >= [data count]) { 
        //Use default style for the last cell.
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierDefault] autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: I think you should just make the last cell `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. It is much easier than any thing you have mentioned above.

Comment: But I need the subtitles... How do I display text.detailTextLabel if I use the default style?

Comment: you have to do it only for the last row not for any other rows.(As you asked in ur question.)

Comment: In that case you can refer to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@the_great_monkey:

You can change the `cellIdentifier` for the cell where you want this center alignment.

For the other cells you should keep one common `cellIdentifier`.

Then when you do this

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment  = UITextAlignmentCenter;
cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment  = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Then simply you need to check if `cellIdentifier` is the one for the cell which requires center alignment?

If Yes, then apply,

`cell.textLabel.textAlignment  = UITextAlignmentCenter;` and `cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment  = UITextAlignmentCenter;` for that cell.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How do I check the cellIdentifier for a cell? I tried if(cell.cellIdentifier == cellSubtitle) but it doesn't work...

Comment: @the_great_monkey: You are welcome. Sorry didnt reply to your first comment as was not available online. But I am glad that it helped you!! :-)

Comment: I've also updated the question with my code... after several google searches, I thought it might worth sticking up code there. Nothing on google gives the source code. Thank you!

Comment: @the_great_monkey: Yeah great work!! Good to see this gesture to help others. Keep it up!!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to load a cell from a .xib, which lets you arrange the cell's subviews any way you like. Unfortunately, UITableViewCell's textLabel and detailTextLabel properties aren't IBOutlets, so you can't connect the labels that you'd like to use for these properties in IB.

One way to handle this is to connect those views to outlets in your controller instead, and use them when you set up the cell in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. That's fine if you won't need to change the content of the cell later. In that case, you can just create a nib containing a UITableViewCell, set the type of File's Owner to match your controller, and set up the cell's subviews however you like and connect them to File's Owner. See [Loading Custom TableView Cells from Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) for more information.

The other way to go is to create a UITableViewCell subclass that has outlets for the text label and detail label. Then do the same as above, but use your subclass rather than UITableViewCell. Once you've created this subclass, you can use it with different .xibs if you want different layouts at some point. The work needed to create the subclass is minimal, and it becomes a useful and reusable tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextBorderStyleLine;
```